# Cloud sql support Non English Letter ?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I have created new api in google app engine using google cloud endpoint module.
Created api contains api method, this method have connect cloud SQL table for insert and extract operation. Now its under development only so used MySQL for development,here when i try to insert non English letters shows only ?.

My doubt is if suppose moved on cloud SQL this problem was solved or not?

If suppose want to change a code for handle non English letters ? and how?

Answer (score 0):

First, you will want to make sure that the character set used for your tables is utf8mb4. The default character set in mysql in latin1.

You can set the character set on the database using:

```
ALTER DATABASE db CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Note that this won't affect existing tables in the database. If this is a new database and you don't care about the data yet, it would be simpler to re-create the tables using utf8mb4.

Comment: Yes i did this ALTER DATABASE dbName CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE employee_location CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;